# UILabel Animated Letter

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift3, uilabel

I am trying to make an animation as seen in the picture. In the example code I give, the characters after the click are overlaid. How can I make an animation like in the picture.

Thank you.

[image: Letter animation]

```
func letterTapAction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    for label in lettesLabel {
        if sender.view == label {
            copyLabelAndAnimate(fromLabel: label)
        }
    }
}

func copyLabelAndAnimate(fromLabel: UILabel) {
    let copiedLabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x: fromLabel.frame.minX, y: fromLabel.frame.minY ,width: fromLabel.bounds.width, height: fromLabel.bounds.height))
    copiedLabel.text = fromLabel.text!
    copiedLabelsTagCounter += 1
    copiedLabel.tag = copiedLabelsTagCounter
    copiedLabel.font = UIFont.init(name: "Noteworthy-Bold", size: 28.0)
    view.addSubview(copiedLabel)


    //UIView.removeFromSuperview(view.viewWithTag(101)!)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        copiedLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint.init(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2 + CGFloat(self.spaceForCopiedLabels), y: self.view.frame.minY + CGFloat(15))
    })

    if lettersThatNeedLessSpace.characters.contains(copiedLabel.text!.characters.first!) {
        spaceForCopiedLabels -= 8
    }

    spaceForCopiedLabels += 25

}
```

Comment: You already asked the same question yesterday.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it yesterday. Comments and answers were written. But I can not reach the question. I know this is a violation, but I have to.

Answer (score 2):

In general:

- Have 1 letter per label (so 10 of them in your example) and manage them from a class for the bottom area.
- Don't copy the labels but simply move them from bottom to the line, while also changing `backgroundColor` and `textColor`.
- Create a class that manages the line. Create a method in the line class that calculates the center coordinate of the next letter, when one would be added.

When user taps a letter at bottom:

- Ask the line object the coordinate of the next letter.
- Convert that line coordinate to the coordinate space of the bottom area.
- Do a simple `UIView` animation from the bottom area to the new coordinate.
- When the animation is initiated, tell the line that a new letter is coming. This will allow the line object to move its existing letters a bit to the left.
- When the animation completes, you could move the tapped `UILabel` from the view hierarchy of the bottom area to the line.